# Tirar tag do html pelo css na responsividade

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, html-tags

To querendo tirar a tag `<br>` do html pelo css para responsividade

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="chamada1">
            <h2>Sistemas Próprios Para <br> Empresas Autênticas</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width:600px){

.chamda1 h2{}
}
```

Tipo é p/ no responsivo não fique com uma quebra de linha no texto pra mim aplicar estilos no texto livremente sem essa quebra.

Comment: Sobre esconder um elemento, já tem várias postagens no site explicando como fazer (com o `<br>` é mesma coisa) - Mas para fins de aprendizado, o problema do seu caso específico é que está usando `<br>` para estilização, e a finalidade dele não é essa. Se quer estilizar um pedaço específico do cabeçalho de maneira diferente sem problema semântico, pode usar <span> no trecho desejado, e mudar o tipo de display ou layout com CSS puro. Ainda lembrando que a associação que fez de px com a largura do texto é problemática. Se quer insistir nessa idéia pode fazer algo até mais simples:

Comment: `Sistemas&nbsp;Próprios&nbsp;para Empresas&nbsp;Autênticas` - o &nbsp é o espaço inquebrável (pode ser substituido pelo unicode equivalente se quiser evitar uso legado de htmlentities). Desta forma, o texto será quebrado apenas no espaço convencional se necessário (o browser cuida disso sem `@media`). Note que não é recomendação do melhor meio, só comentei por ser mais simples e um pouco "menos pior" que o `<br>`. O ideal é realmente pensar na semântica e evitar a situação atual, que é denominada [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70)

Answer (score -2):

Podes adicionar para o br ficar com um "display: none" caso o width máx seja 600px. Por exemplo:

```css
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .chamda1 h2 {}
  br {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chamada1">
  <h2>Sistemas Próprios Para <br class="responsive-br"> Empresas Autênticas</h2>
  <p>Lorem <br>ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Se for o caso de apenas esse br não aparecer, então cria uma classe específica de estilo para ele. Como em:

```css
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .chamda1 h2 {}
  .responsive-br {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chamada1">
  <h2>Sistemas Próprios Para <br class="responsive-br"> Empresas Autênticas</h2>
  <p>Lorem <br>ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Já testou isso em diferentes navegadores? Você sabe se funciona no Safari ou no Firefox?

Comment: Testei no Chrome e Firefox

Comment: Parece que não funciona no FireFox? Correto?

Comment: Funcionou em ambos